# How to update Drupal for CiviCRM?

Tags: drupal, upgrade

Quick question - is there anything in particular to take into consideration when upgrading Drupal, if it is used as a platform for CiviCRM?

Or can I just go ahead with Drupal update as if there was not CiviCRM installed?

Comment: pls clarify what you mean by 'update'

Comment: In this case I meant minor version upgrade.

Comment: @Aivars - if one of the answers below answers your question can you accept the answer using the "Tick" button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the upgrade i.e from 6.x to 7.x to 8.x. If its a simple and internal version i.e 7.12 to 7.29 than you can perform update directly and you won't have problem in CiviCRM but if its from 6 to 7/8 then you will need to replace the CiviCRM files with same version for D7 or D8 and then clear CiviCRM cache(probably delete template_c).

> **Note: Backup Database and filesystem before performing upgrade.**

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to upgrade within a major version (7.x to 7.x) (6.x to 6.x) (8.x.x to 8.x.x) of Drupal without experiencing any major issues however as with any upgrade it is recommended to take a full backup before you attempt the upgrade.